# How to count numbers that represent money using Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I count how many Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, and Pennies are in $10?

I know I need a while, but I don't know what would be the condition in while.

Then I did this:

```
while(#read from a file)
print $cents
$left = $cents %25 #i did this since quarter is the largest change we have.
```

After that I don't know how to proceed with writing how many quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies there are.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to figure out change, work in cent amounts (not dollar amounts), and subtract the maximum number of the largest coin, then the maximum number of the next largest coin, etc. With coin values of 1,5,10,25, I think this will always arrive at the answer that uses the fewest coins (though this will not be the case for different available coins).

```
my $amount_in_cents = 1000;  # $10 * 100¢/$

my @coins = (25, 10, 5, 1);
my @change;
for my $coin (@coins) { 
   push @change, int($amount_in_cents / $coin);
   $amount_in_cents -= $change[-1] * $coin;
}

say join ', ', map "$change[$_]x$coins[$_]¢", grep $change[$_], 0..$#coins;
```

Comment: The greedy change-making algorithm is optimal when each coin is at least twice as large as the next.

Comment: @Greg Bacon, nifty, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at how to work with one coin:

```
my $break_apart = 1000; # ten dollars, in pennies
my $break_into = 25; # a quarter
my $remainder = $break_apart % $break_into;
my $count = ($break_apart - $remainder) / $break_into;
```

Then expand that to work with multiple coins:

```
my @coins = (1, 5, 10, 25);
my $break_apart = 1000; # ten dollars, in pennies
for my $break_into (@coins)
{
    my $remainder = $break_apart % $break_into;
    my $count = ($break_apart - $remainder) / $break_into;
}
```